# Assumptions discharge, proof summary and labelling with bussproof

Tags: logic, proof-package, bussproofs

[image]

Is it possible with `bussproof` package obtain this kind of formula-layout?:

(1) Assumptions discharge with four vertical dots;

(2) Four vertical dots for proof summary;

(3) Labelling with a number (in this case "1.") over a formula.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying using the `\noLine` option.  For instance, to get a "1." above "[A]" above dots, use:

```
\AxiomC{\small 1.}
\noLine
\UnaryInfC{[$A$]}
\noLine
\UnaryInfC{$\vdots$}
```

The `\vdots` gives only three dots.  One way to get four dots is define a LaTeX command to place four periods vertically in a vbox.  Alternately, the LaTeX "stix dots" package includes a `\fourvdots` command.

`\small` should give small font (alternate: `\footnotesize`)

The `\extraVskip` command can be used to adjust the white space between lines in the derivation.

(Caveat: I have not tested to code above in an actual LaTeX file.  If there are any bugs in the code, let me know and I can update.)

Answer (score 2):

The `ebproof` package provide an handy solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
    {\color{red}\textbf{(1)}}
     \begin{prooftree}
        \Hypo{A \vee B}
        \Hypo{[A]}
        \Ellipsis{}{C }
        \Hypo{[B] }
        \Ellipsis{}{C }
        \Infer3[$\vee\textrm{E}$]{C}
     \end{prooftree}
     &
     {\color{red}\textbf{(2)}}
      \begin{prooftree}
        \Hypo{}
        \Ellipsis{}{ A}
        \Hypo{}
        \Ellipsis{}{ B}
        \Infer[no rule, separation=-0.4em, rule margin=-.3em]2{}
      \Ellipsis{}{C}
      \end{prooftree}
      &
      {\color{red}\textbf{(3)}}
      \begin{prooftree}
        \Hypo{\stackrel{1}{[A]}}
        \Infer[right label ={\(\supset I.1.\)}]{1}{A \supset A}
      \end{prooftree}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Especially considering the fact that space can be easily adjusted (have a look at [the documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/ebproof), section 4.2, Spacing).

Answer (score 1):

I tried with this code

```
\begin{center}
\AxiomC{$A \vee B$}
    \alwaysNoLine
    \AxiomC{[$A$]}
    \UnaryInfC{\vdots}
    \UnaryInfC{$C$}
        \AxiomC{[$B$]}
        \UnaryInfC{\vdots}
        \UnaryInfC{$C$}
        \alwaysSingleLine
\TrinaryInfC{$C$}
\DisplayProof
\hspace{25pt}
\alwaysNoLine
\AxiomC{\small 1.}
\UnaryInfC{[$A$]}
\alwaysSingleLine
\UnaryInfC{$A \to B$}
\DisplayProof
\end{center}
```

I used `\alwaysNoLine` instead of `\noline`. That is the result for (1) and (3) instances: [image]

Unfortunately, there's too much space between formulas in square brackets. There's a new package called `prftree.sty` where is possible obtain those kind of layout but 1) it's not intuitive as `bussproof`; 2) I can't use it because it goes in contrast with `bussproof` and I don't have time to change every formula wrote earlier with `bussproof`.

Anyway thank you for your help!

Comment: I presume you mean there is too much space separating the formulas in square brackets from the `\vdots`.  You can adjust this in two ways: First option, if you do not need to doit very often, adjust the \extraVspace to be less than the default 2pt, perhaps even to a negative value.   Second option that works better if you are using it a lot: define a different version of `\vdots` that is in a box with less height.

Comment: Thank you! For (3) I found a really simple and intuitive solution...i posted it in this page.

Comment: @SamBuss I'm assuming you've at some point determined a good size box to put \vdots in for this purpose. I'm curious what you've found and if you might want to share your code.

Answer (score 0):

For schema n. (3) I found a really simple solution. Using bussproof, the code is:

`\begin{prooftree}
\AxiomC{[$\overset{1.}{A}$]}
\UnaryInfC{$A \to B$}
\end{prooftree}`

Comment: `\stackrel{1}{[A]}`, that I proposed in my solution, is probably a nicer way to obtain this result.